# Adding information to Golang Gin HTTP error responses

Tags: mongodb, rest, go, go-gin

I am trying to return a custom error response when an HTTP 500 Internal Error is encountered. If I use c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, CustomError{}) when a database write error occurs, Gin ignores my CustomError struct and substitutes a default "500 server Error" message.

How can I add information to the default response or return a custom response while still using the HTTP 500 Internal Server error code?

This is what I am trying to accomplish. Notifying users of a duplicate entry in the Mongo database. Gin ignores my DBErrorResponse struct and just returns the default 500 error json response.

```
_, err := handler.collection.InsertOne(handler.ctx, data)
   if err != nil {
       if mongo.IsDuplicateKeyError(err) {
          dbErr := err.(mongo.WriteException)
           c.JSON(
               http.StatusInternalServerError,
               models.DBErrorResponse{
                   Type: "Write Exception",
                   Code: dbErr.WriteErrors[0].Code,
                   Err:  "similar record exists",
               })

           return
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

If the error is caused by a user providing a duplicate key, it's not an internal server error. You might want to use something like `BadRequest(400)`, which suits duplicate value far more, if provided by the client. Thus, you should be able to return a custom error message with StatusCode 400.

Additionally, as far as I know, `InternalServerError(500)` is not designed to provide a 'server-side' problem feedback to the client, since, well, it's not public information. Although I'm not certainly sure if that's so and if is, why.

UPD: As Gavin mentioned, httpCode 409 is far better choice, here is the doc:

> HTTP 409 error status: The HTTP 409 status code (Conflict) indicates that the request could not be processed because of conflict in the request, such as the requested resource is not in the expected state, or the result of processing the request would create a conflict within the resource.

Comment: A 409 may be even more fitting than a 400.

Comment: @Gavin Absolutely agree, will update answer to make it easier to notice.

Comment: I will try a 409, however http.StatusBadRequest also prevented the custom error from being returned.

Comment: Doesn't work either. It returns this: {"error":"409 Client Error: Conflict for url: https://172.255.255.3:8080/data"}

Comment: @Кафка Is your `models.DBErrorResponse` JSON file? Did you `json.Marshall()` it?

Comment: I did not explicitly marshal the struct, but when returning a 200 HTTP code, there is no need to. I just use the struct. I'm pretty certain that Gin takes care of the Marshaling in the c.JSON method. I have it working now using httpStatusOK.

Comment: @Кафка Looking through the source, there is a function [bodyAllowedForStatus](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/8cd11c82e447f74d63e3da6037cb0463440d8e16/context.go#L841-L851) used as part of rendering the JSON. This should return `true` for the status codes you're providing. Can you please update your question to provide a minimal, reproducible example of the issue you're experiencing?

Comment: @Gavin I wrote a simple test to demonstrate the issue, but the test passed sending back the custom response. I will run a few more using more complicated logic and then post the code that fails here.

Comment: It turns out that Gin is returning the errors as expected, but I have the server behind an NGINX reverse proxy and NGINX is intercepting the error body from Gin API and substituting its own JSON error response for the custom response Gin is returning. Now I just need to figure out how to get NGINX to just pass back the response Gin returns, but that is another issue.

Comment: Turns out it wasn't NGINX after all. I have a front-end for the API used for quick testing. It was intercepting the response and returning the error instead of the response body. I've gotten everything to work as expected now.